# SimpleModal not centering when opened

Tags: jquery, plugins, center, simplemodal

I'm using the SimpleModal jquery plugin. Everything works fine in FireFox but in all of the other browers the modal window isn't centered on the screen when it first opens. It appears that the top-left corner of the window is at the center of the screen. Once I close the window and then reopen it or if I resize the browser window, it's centered properly. Anyone have any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you post code plz? That would be awesome.

Comment: $('#modalimg').modal({ overlayClose: true, opacity: 70, overlayCss: { backgroundColor: "#000", cursor: 'pointer' }, position: [, ] });

Comment: I added "position: [,]" later thinking to force it to center even though that's the default but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. I had to set the width and/or height of the container. Setting containerCss, minHeight, minWidth, maxHeight, maxWidth did it.

Answer (score 0):

#### As a quick fix :

Put this in `doc ready`

```
$(window).resize();
```

or what you can do is look for this kind of `.resize()` function and add this to the closing tag.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   //.....centering stuff.......
}).resize();
//^-------^---this will resize when doc gets ready and '.resize()' happens
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery has option for position  [Jqueru ui position](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position)

```
$('my-selector').dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
```

from Docs

> Specifies where the dialog should be displayed. The dialog will handle
>   collisions such that as much of the dialog is visible as possible.String: A string 
>   representing the position within the viewport. Possible values:
>   "center", "left", "right", "top", "bottom"

.